# ClassNotFoundException Applet code after updating JRE 1.7u45

Tags: java, jar, applet, classnotfoundexception, codebase

My applet is working fine with JRE1.6. Here is the HTML that defines Applet tag:

```
<applet
archive="MainJar.jar,
lib/Lib1.jar,
lib/Lib2.jar, 
lib/Lib3.jar,
lib/Lib4.jar"

name = "My App"
code= "start.MainClass.class"
width=1280 height=800>
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx512m">
<param name="cache_option" value="no">
</applet>
```

My main Applet Code is packaged under `start.MainClass.class` of `MainJar.jar`.

`MainJar.jar` is same directory (`MyPath`) with this HTML. Other archives are under `MyPath/lib` folder.

Once I update JRE to latest version (1.7u45), 1st warning message I have is related to permission. Then I added permission as well as others attributes to jar manifest after googling for solution:

```
Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Application-Name: My App
```

Then the 1st warning disappear. However, I get 2nd error which is:

```
ClassNotFoundException: start.MainClass.class
```

Then I check tomcat access log, here is the 404 error:

```
GET MyPath/start/emsWeb20.class HTTP/1.1" 404 1045
```

Any idea why it send GET request for the applet class under `MyPath` but not my `MainJar.jar`?
It only happened once I update to JRE1.7.